# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. for array elements?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Components code is:

```
this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

Form is:

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
<div
      class="form-group"
      formArrayName="items"
      *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index"
    >
</div>
</form>
```

I get error message:

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

How can I fix it:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
get items() : FormArry {
 return this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray
}
```

template

```html
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  <div formArrayName="items">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index">
     ...
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In this case it does not work: `this.items.push(this.createItem());`;

Comment: I need setter too